# Sending visualisations along with table in gmailR

Tags: r, visualization

I am trying to attach a bar chart in an email but not getting a desired result. That is I'm returning table but not able to print bar chart.

```
library(ggvis)

bar <- data %>%
  ggvis(~supplier_city, ~no_of_orders, fill="blue") %>% 
  layer_bars()

# importing libraries
library(gmailr)
library(RMySQL)
library(tableHTML)

# preparing the body
msg = tableHTML(data, rownames = FALSE)

html_bod <- paste0("<p> Maximum order Time </p>", time, bar, msg)

# sending mail
use_secret_file("/Users/abhi/Downloads/gmailR.json")

mime() %>%
  to("1234@gmail.com") %>%
  from("1234@p.in") %>%
  subject("Data ") %>%
  html_body(html_bod) %>%
  send_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. One problem you have here is that your r object, `bar`, is not an html object. The table and text should work though.

Comment: This may help: https://mailtrap.io/blog/r-send-email/